# Access 2003: Any complications with switching from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

MS Access newbie here who got assigned the task of researching to see if we could convert from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012 db without any complications other than changing the server connection string inside our Access 2003 .adp.  Just wondering if someone has done this and what issues they encountered.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to depend entirely on what you use and how your DB is designed.  You'll need to examine the [Engine Backward Compatibility documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143532(v=sql.100).aspx) and check to see if there are any issues which would block your migration.

They are broken down by version and generally only cover the immediate version prior to the one you're looking at, so you'll need to examine the documents for SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2, and SQL Server 2012 and compare it to what you use in SQL Server 2005.  Note the drop down menu entitled "Other versions" which lets you change between versions.

Answer (score 0):

We did this with no issues whatsoever.  As long as your SQL Server is set up with the same permissions (read/write) you shouldn't have any problems.

Now, switching from Access 2003 to Access 2010 was another issue entirely.